# Why are these conda installs different sizes due to the different channel, even though the version and build are exactly the same?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I tried to install git package using conda and compared two different commands:

- `conda install git`
- `conda install -c anaconda git`

I was offered two packages with the same versions and builds but different file size. Just curious as to why this is?

```
(camera-calibration-python) C:\Users\XXX> conda install git

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    git-2.34.1                 |       haa95532_0        50.4 MB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        50.4 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  git                pkgs/main/win-64::git-2.34.1-haa95532_0


(camera-calibration-python) C:\Users\XXX> conda install -c anaconda git
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: C:\Users\joini\anaconda3\envs\camera-calibration-python

  added / updated specs:
    - git


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    git-2.34.1                 |       haa95532_0        95.5 MB  anaconda
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:        95.5 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  git                anaconda/win-64::git-2.34.1-haa95532_0
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this. Namely, `conda search --info main/win-64::git=2.34.1` and `conda search --info anaconda/win-64::git=2.34.1` yield exactly the same information (both 95MB files with identical hashes). Are you using a proxy for the **main** location? Perhaps add some info on your configuration to the question (e.g., output of `conda config --show-sources`).

Comment: Output is just `==> C:\Users\xxx\.condarc <==
channels:
  - defaults`

Comment: Can you run the search commands I did and do they show different info?

Comment: No, they show exactly the same info.